# Can not add maven github package in spring boot gradle project as dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle, github-package-registry, github-packages

We want to add [this github package](https://github.com/catenax-ng/product-lab-ssi/packages/1842305) to our gradle project.

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.ssi.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/catenax-ng/product-lab-ssi")
        credentials {
            username = 'nitin-vavdiya'
            password = 'ghp_my-PAT'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.tractusx.ssi:cx-ssi-lib:0.0.3'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I build the project using `./gradlew build` I am getting package not found error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration66'.
   > Could not find org.eclipse.tractusx.ssi:cx-ssi:0.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/tractusx/ssi/cx-ssi/0.0.3/cx-ssi-0.0.3.pom
       - https://maven.pkg.github.com/catenax-ng/product-lab-ssi/org/eclipse/tractusx/ssi/cx-ssi/0.0.3/cx-ssi-0.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :
```

Here the pom file link is generated wrong, **-lib** is missing.

```
 - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/tractusx/ssi/cx-ssi/0.0.3/cx-ssi-0.0.3.pom
 - https://maven.pkg.github.com/catenax-ng/product-lab-ssi/org/eclipse/tractusx/ssi/cx-ssi/0.0.3/cx-ssi-0.0.3.pom
```

How to reproduce?

- Checkout [source code here](https://github.com/nitin-vavdiya/ssi-test)
- Change password in build.gradle
- run `./gradlew build`

Can you help to identify what is wrong here?